# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu not working in Master Page

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot get my Bootstrap drop down menu to work. By not working I mean, nothing happens when I click on the link, nothing drops down. I have created my nav bar in a masterpage. I have also spent half a day reading all of the posts on here and I cannot get it to work...

I am creating an application in VS2013 Pro and it is in ASP.NET/C# 4.0, I have tried it in Chrome, IE, Firefox etc. I have also swapped JQuery min with JQuery main, tried it at the top and bottom of the html. I have been through every permutation. I have also checked the inspector in each of the browsers and cannot see any errors. I have changed the code for the navbar from looking at the posts available and I am now at a dead end.

I have checked my code in fiddlr and it works, but in my master page it will not work at all. The masterpage code is as follows:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/EMS/EMSDefault.master.cs" Inherits="The_SumTechnology_Project.EMS.EMSDefault" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Matt's Test</title>    
     <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
    </script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body style="background-color: transparent;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>                    
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white;">SumTechnology EMS</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNav">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sites
                               <b class="caret"></b> 
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Buildings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Meters</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Data</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Reports</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Account</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a runat="server" href="#" title="Manage your account">Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still cannot find why the JS wont load, even having tested it. But for some reason I keep getting the following error, that is probably unrelated when building the App:

***Warning  11  No way to resolve conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Choosing "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" arbitrarily.    The SumTechnology Project***

To get around the issue I used CDN references for the JS elements for the page and this has fixed it. So it is a conflict in something that is preventing those particular JS files from running.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine, I pasted it in a project I'm working and the dropdown is working.
I don't know why are you calling 
<

```
script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
    </script>
```

without it, the dropdown still works, try checking if you don't have a conflict in the page.

Comment: One of the posts on here said it won't work without the extra JS for the dropdown, I've removed it and it still won't work. Do you have any suggestions for looking for conflicts?

Comment: I have also just opened the project on another machine and published it and it still wont work, so it has something to do with the VS build using IIS express...I think?

Comment: bootstrap works on the client side, is pure css and js.

Answer (score 0):

I never use

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
    </script>
```

in fact, I tested your code without it and works perfect,
you should look if you are making a good calling of the bootstrap js file, or maybe the version of jquery is not compatible

Comment: I'm kinda out of ideas...what would you reccomend trying in the way of testing the js calls...